# Difference between two datetime properties in model (c#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have model with 2 `DateTime` properties

Here is code

```
    sing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace GoogleMapsAsp_Net.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Park
    {
        public int parkId { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeStart { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeEnd { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public TimeSpan? Difference { get { return TimeStart - TimeEnd; } }
    }
}
```

I want to calculate difference between them in minutes and write difference in new property. So I wrote this property

```
public TimeSpan? Difference { get { return TimeStart - TimeEnd; } }
```

But when I run project I have this error

> 'The specified type member 'Difference' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Here is my method on back end where I try to take difference from model property

```
public JsonResult GetPlaces()
    {
        using (var ctx = new GoogleMapsAsp_NetContext())
        {
             const int coeff = 2; 
            var items = ctx.Parks.Select(
                x => new
                {
                    lng = x.Longitude,
                    lat = x.Latitude,
                    difference = x.Difference
                }
            ).ToList();
            return Json(items.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

How I can calculate it correctly

Comment: Use a view model - that property should not be part of your data model

Comment: are you using the `Difference` property in a `Where` clause ? If so, you may rely on one of the System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Diff* functions instead of `Difference`

Comment: It is still not clear why you would want to calculate the Difference at the database level. Is it involved in an `OrderBy`, with a `Take ? involving coeff ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `Distance` property in the query that is executed in the database, which is not possible. Add `AsEnumerable` to bring the data before using the property:

```
var items = ctx.Parks.AsEnumerable().Select(
            x => new {
                lng = x.Longitude,
                lat = x.Latitude,
                difference = x.Difference
            }).ToArray();
```

*No need to first create it as a `List` and then call `ToArray`. Just use `ToArray` once*

---

Previously irrelevant answered: 
Use the `[NotMapped]` attribute so EF ignores the property:

```
[NotMapped]
public TimeSpan? Difference { get { return TimeStart - TimeEnd; } }
```

Or better still as @Stephen commented: *Use a view model - that property should not be part of your data model*

Comment: And in case its not added, `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`.

Comment: To add to this wonderful answer, the second line is redundant; `DateTime? - DateTime?` already returns `TimeSpan?` and works correctly on `null` values (i.e. returns `null`).

Comment: @decPL - ops true! Thanks. Checked and you are correct. Updated answer

Comment: I still have this error. After adding `[NotMapped]`

Comment: @marc_spencer - Did you also follow Keyur's comment?

Comment: The problem is that the property is used directly in a LINQ-to-Entities query. That's not possible, even with the `NotMapped` attribute.

Comment: @GertArnold - you are correct. My mistake. Corrected answer now after seeing code that leads to error

Comment: @marc_spencer - was my mistake. Misunderstood the problem. See update

Comment: @marc_spencer - did the update help you solve the problem?